# How to fill 2D array with randm colors in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I've been trying to generate a grid of randomly colored boxes for a brick-breaker game. However given this code, the colors keep changing. I'd like them to be randomly set and stay that way.

```
for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < map [0].length; j++) {
            if(map[i][j] > 0) { //make brick if greater than 0, else don't 

                int color = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
                g.setColor(new Color(color, color, color));
                g.fillRect(j * brickWidth + 80, i * brickHeight + 50, brickWidth, brickHeight);


                g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawRect(j * brickWidth + 80, i * brickHeight + 50, brickWidth, brickHeight);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Create the 2d array once in your constructor and only read from it when painting.

Answer (score 0):

Each time your component need to be resized or moved, `repaint()` method is being called to update it's state. So if you are generating colors in `paintComponent` like in following example:

```
public class MyComponent extends JComponent {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // generate colors and draw grid
    }
}
```

then colors will change on resize event or other event that lead to `repaint` call, since `repaint` invokes `paintComponent` method. If you want to display the same colors, just move generate-colors code out of this method:

```
public class MyComponent extends JComponent {

    private final Color[][] gridColors = randomGridColors(5, 5);

    private Color[][] randomGridColors(int rows, int columns) {
        Color[][] gridColors = new Color[rows][columns];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                gridColors [i][j] = randomColor();
            } 
        }
    }

    private Color randomColor() {
        int rgbValue = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        return new Color(rgbValue, rgbValue, rgbValue);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // draw grid 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You currently create the random color every time you draw your bricks, which can be many times per second.
Create some brick class and generate the color for each brick only once.
Something like this:

```
public class TryThis {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TryThis.class.getName());

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingComponent panel = new SwingComponent();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("try me");
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

static class SwingComponent extends JPanel {

    int W = 10;
    int H = 10;
    int recwidth = 20;
    int recheight = 10;

    Brick[][] bricks = new Brick[H][W];

    public SwingComponent() {
        super();
        for (int y = 0; y < H; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < W; x++) {
                bricks[y][x] = new Brick(createRandomColor(), new Rectangle(x * recwidth, y * recheight, recwidth,
                    recheight));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        for (int y = 0; y < H; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < W; x++) {
                bricks[y][x].draw(g);
            }
        }
    }

    Color createRandomColor() {
        return new Color((int) (Math.random() * 256), (int) (Math.random() * 256), (int) (Math.random() * 256));
    }
}

static class Brick {

    Color col;
    Rectangle rec;

    public Brick(Color col, Rectangle rec) {
        this.col = col;
        this.rec = rec;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(col);
        g.fillRect(rec.x, rec.y, rec.width, rec.height);
    }
}
}
```